# `pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH

Tags: python, keras, jupyter, graphviz, pydot

[My jupyter server is running in a gcp deep learning vm.](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/)

I'm trying to print the model in a Jupyter notebook cell.

```
import os, sys
from utils.models.alexnet import alexnet
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = alexnet(len(class_names))
model.summary()
plot_model(model, to_file="alexnet_model.png", show_shapes=True)
```

I get this error

```
`pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz ([https://www.graphviz.org/](https://www.graphviz.org/)) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.
```

I have correctly installed Graphviz in my machine with

`apt-get install graphviz`

```
stat /usr/bin/dot
  File: /usr/bin/dot
  Size: 10568       Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 142872      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-02-10 11:48:19.416617639 +0000
Modify: 2017-02-19 10:32:17.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-12-13 01:47:41.084977709 +0000
```

The python packages pydot, pydot-ng, pydotplus are also installed.

This is my path variable

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

`/user/bin` is included here.

**EDIT**

When executed in a jupyter notebook shell.

```
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

`/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

**Another wierd thing**

I have a simple image dataset with 3 classes and altogether around 2000 images. In my jupyter notebook I first process and load the images into memory. Creating the model and printing it comes next. With the simple dataset it works without error. This happens when I work with large datasets.

Comment: You installed locally the dot tool, but shouldn't this be on the cloud server? Is it 100% sure that the path that is used in jupyter is having the `/usr/bin` in its path (check inside the place where you want to use it)?

Comment: What does `os.path.exists('/usr/bin/dot')` emit when executed in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It returns True

Comment: Thank you -- that affirms that `dot` is installed on your GCP node, not just your local client.

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting the same thing so i install conda install python-graphviz
after conda install pydot

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I solved it by following the Answer of [Prerna Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13662888/prerna-verma). By the way, there are three steps for using graphviz in Linux Envs:

1. `sudo apt-get install graphviz` ([download and install graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/download/), if you are a Windows User)
2. `conda install pydot`
3. `conda install python-graphviz`

then, you can use it!

Comment: Use `$ dot -V` to check if the graphviz installed successful

Answer (score 1):

`conda` installs only binary files of `graphviz`, but you need to install Python dependencies also. So install both of them with:

```
conda install graphviz    

conda install python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me :

```
sudo apt install python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz
```

refer issue in : https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/issues/36